# Changing between 2 background colours on mouse Y + adapting <p> to that new colour

Tags: javascript, ruby, sass, mouseevent, haml

I found a piece of code that almost does what I want except I want it to be horizontal / based on mouse Y instead of X. Now I understand that in the js X will be changed to Y, but I struggle with rotating the divs.

Also, if I want to put some text over it, how would I do so that the background change affects the text colour (so if the text is black and half of the background is black, to make sure once when the black background overlays the text, text colour changes to another or gets inverted for example?

Also also, I tried to figure out in js which part dictates the responsiveness of the mouse movement, i.e., how would you do so that the colour shifting is not lagging after the mouse but I couldn't figure out?

https://codepen.io/erutuf/pen/NJLwqV

haml

```
    #banner-wrapper.banner-wrapper
  .banner.design
    .banner-content

  .banner.dev
    .banner-content
```

scss

```
   body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  .banner-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden; background:red;
  }

  .banner {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;

    &.dev {
      margin-left: -500px;
      width: calc(50vw + 500px);
      .banner-content {
        margin-left: 500px; background:black;
      }
    }
    .banner-content {
      height: 400px;
    }
    img {
      width: 100vw;
    }
  }
}
```

js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    let banner = document.getElementById('banner-wrapper');
    let devLayer = banner.querySelector('.dev');
    let delta = 0;

    banner.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
        delta = (e.clientX - window.innerWidth / 2) * 0.5;
        devLayer.style.width = e.clientX + 500 + delta + 'px';
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can play with JS + CSS. The following code can be your starting point :).

btw i'm adapting code from your link https://codepen.io/erutuf/pen/NJLwqV

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    let banner = document.getElementById("banner-wrapper");
    let devLayer = banner.querySelector(".dev");
    let delta = 0;
    // play with div's height
    banner.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
        delta = (e.clientY - window.innerHeight / 2) * 0.5;
        devLayer.style.height = e.clientY + delta + "px";
    });
})
```

```html
<div class="banner-wrapper" id="banner-wrapper">
  <div class="banner design">
    <div class="banner-content">BANNER TEXT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="banner dev">
    <div class="banner-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body .banner-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
}
body .banner {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body .banner.dev {
  width: 100%;
  /* play with responsiveness here. note that 0.1 is more responsive than 0.5. more info : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp */
  -webkit-transition: height 0.2s linear;
  transition: height 0.2s ease;
}
body .banner.dev .banner-content {
  background: black;
}
body .banner .banner-content {
  height: 400px;
}
body .banner img {
  width: 100%;
}
.banner.design {
    margin-top: -25px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    font-size: 50px;
 /* set color & mix-blend-mode for text color vs background color effect. more info : https://css-tricks.com/methods-contrasting-text-backgrounds/ */
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: -175px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 350px;
}

</style>
```